# TimePickerDialog Constructor Issues

Tags: java, android, timepickerdialog

```
if (v == btnEndTimePicker) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance() ;
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(true, this,
                    (view, hour, minutes) -> {
                        return editStartTime.setText((hour + ":" + minutes), mHour, mMinutes);
                    });
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
        if (v == btnStartTimePicker) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance() ;
            sHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            sMinutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            CalendarDialog timePickerDialog = new CalendarDialog(true, this,
                    (view, hour, minutes) -> {
                        return editStartTime.setText((hour + ":" + minutes), sHour, sMinutes);
                    });
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
```

I'm not sure what to do here, I used a similar code to pop up a Calendar Date Dialog and choose a date that is then dropped into an EditText field. When I do it for TimePickerDialog it says it  it's expecting a char[] not a String.

Comment: Where exactly its expecting char[]?

Comment: Posting the logs would help.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this. This is what it says when being built in Android Studio:

Comment: error: no suitable constructor found for TimePickerDialog(AppointmentEditorActivity,(view,hour[...]s); })
            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                               ^
    constructor TimePickerDialog.TimePickerDialog(Context,OnTimeSetListener,int,int,boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor TimePickerDialog.TimePickerDialog(Context,int,OnTimeSetListener,int,int,boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Give Wrong Parameters to TimePickerDialog object its get

```
     public TimePickerDialog (Context context,  
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener, 
            int hourOfDay, 
            int minute, 
            boolean is24HourView)
```

replace this

```
  TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(true, this,
                (view, hour, minutes) -> {
                    return editStartTime.setText((hour + ":" + minutes), mHour, mMinutes);
                });
```

with

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,listener,2,25,true);
```

these are right Parameters for more check it out

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog